# How to disable a plugin in joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

I would like to disable a read more plugin ( cutof content) in all pages except my main menu pages in joomla

How do I do this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any method that allows for the actual disabling of a plugin for certain pages. Plugins are either on or off, site-wide. This can be seen from the **Extensions** | **Plugin Manager**, as well as the SQL database: **jos_plugins**. With that said, what would be the purpose in disabling a plugin for certain pages? Most plugins, especially those like a "readmore" are typically setup to be activated by a simple code sequence, such as `{readmore}path/file.htm{/readmore}` and consequently, you can turn the plugin "off" by simply choosing to not use it. Most plugins of that nature provide very little more than essentially "coded access to a CSS class". If you could be more specific on **why** you need to actually disable the plugin for certain pages, perhaps we'd be better equipped to answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the plugin, you could feasibly remove the event trigger that would set the plugin to run, thought it would not be advisable since it would stop that trigger for all plugins and could cause unintended effects.

I am not sure what you mean by "Read more" plugin. You can turn the read more text on and off as a setting in the menu item parameters or in the article itself. Have you tied that?